# How to display a panel upon checkbox select?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

so what I'm trying to accomplish is trying to make my panel show when I tick my CheckBox. Also, I want to hide the div/panel when the CheckBox is unticked.
I have this line in VB.NET side of the application:

```
    pnlWitness.Visible = False

    If cbWitness.Checked = True Then
        pnlWitness.Visible = True
    End If
```

However, when I tick and untick the CheckBox, nothing happens to the panel. Is there something that Ive missed?

EDIT: Here's my code in ASP

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlWitness">
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label id="lblWitnessName"><b>Name</b></label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" id="tbWitnessName" style="width: 150px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2" style="margin-right:15px">
                        <label id="lblWitnessGender"><b>Gender</b></label>
                        <select runat="server" id="cmbWitnessGender" class="form-control" style="width: 155px">
                            <option></option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Female</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                        <label id="lblWitnessContactNo"><b>Contact Number</b></label>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" id="tbWitnessContactNo"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 15px">
                    <label id="lblWitnessRemarks"><b>Remarks</b></label>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbWitnessRemarks"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

And heres my code in VB:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    pnlWitness.Visible = False

    If cbWitness.Checked = True Then
        pnlWitness.Visible = True
    End If

    'Loads the Incident Type from DB
    FillIncidentTypeCmb()

End Sub
```

Comment: Change it to `pnlWitness.Visible = cbWitness.Checked`.

Comment: Where exactly is this code? Event handler or somewhere else? Please update your code to show this.

Comment: @MarkL I've add my ASP and VB code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by adding `AutoPostBack="true"`to my Panel on the ASP side.